# Is editing/creating cached browser resources possible?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser, browser-cache, microsoft-edge

I'm interested in creating a differential updater for some web resources. I currently see 2 ways to do this:

1. Edit the cached version of my resource
2. Create a new browser cached resource from the old cached resource and add the diff pack i request.

Is any scenario possible, and if so, could someone share some resources on this?

Comment: What kind of web resources are you talking about? Do you want to create solution for general case or for some specific case?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev a js script. It's kind of like a plug-n-play. It's under 1mb so i might save it in the storage space.

Comment: Did you consider move pieces of code that changes frequently into separate file and embed version into that file's name?